# How to force laravel to wait until the end job?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

my function in controller Calling parallel and i create a job for use queue in laravel Because parallel call causing the problem

I create queue as follows :

```
public function serve($id)
{
    $this->dispatch(new OrderServeJob($id));
    return response()->json(true);
}
```

and i run:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

But I have a problem with this method

I want laravel to wait until the queue ends up and then return `response()->json(true)`

and after redirect user to another address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your job to be handled before the call ends you should use the `sync`driver for your Job. You can do this customizing the Job connection to use in your job:

```
class OrderServeJob implements ShouldQueue {

    public $connection = 'sync'; // <---


    //

}
```

You can take a look a this (and others) queue configuration in your `config/queue.php` file:

```
'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    //

]
```

---

Check the [Customizing The Queue & Connection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection) section of the documentation.

Comment: This won‘t work anymore if he changes the queue driver to redis e.g. Then he returns the response but doesnt even know if the Job failed or succeeded

Comment: That's why I suggest him to use the sync driver. The sync driver is the same to run the code synchronously. If he use any other driver, the job will be queued so, as you say, it will return just if  job was successfully queued.

Comment: Notice that this configuration only affects this particular job and not the full queue driver. That's why is customized in this particular job class.

Comment: When using the sync driver, the parallel request is not properly handled

Answer (score 0):

You can use queue events. Explanation how to use in the documentation:
[job Events laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events)

Comment: please explain more

Comment: i want after queue ends redirect user to another address

Comment: You cant do that with php cause your frontend doesnt know that your waiting on something. So you can only redirect directly after dispatching the Job to the Queue, or you can perform any task like sending a Mail to the User or update your database after the job has finished. So you cant trigger any frontend action by finishing a Job.

Comment: So what are your suggestions for parallel requests to handle?

Comment: You are probably looking for broadcasting (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) and websockets (https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/). You can notify the client when the job has completed.

Alternatively, you could poll the server to check the status of the job.

Answer (score 0):

U can add ->onConnection('sync') to ur job firing

> $this->dispatch(new OrderServeJob($id))->onConnection('sync');

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain why this solves the issue?

Comment: by using sync connection it is considered a normal function not queue (waiting until process finished)